# how to hide field in same row as field its dependent on

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm pretty novice at jquery but I have a table with a field in each row that is dependent on another field (checkbox) in the row. Since its in a table I need to handle them in bulk. I don't think I'm using next() correctly but I'm trying to grab the next .subnet_mask since it will be the one in the same row as hide it. I'll also have to update it once I get that far so that it handles hiding and showing if the checkbox is checked or not.

```
$(function() {
    $('.dhcp').each(function() {
        $(this).click(function(){
            $('.subnet_mask').next().hide();
        });
    });
});
```

Any help is appreciated!

EDIT: ok ok :) well the page is actually written in VisualForce (for salesforce). For simplicty sake lets say its just a form wrapped around a table (up to 20 rows representing different records) displaying a checkbox field with the class .dhcp and a field after it called .subnet_mask that should be shown/hidden based on the checkbox. Is that helpful?

Comment: Some HTML would be very helpful :)

Comment: Don't 'say' what it is, *show us* what it is. Provide a sample of the rendered HTML (that your browser sees, 'view source'). Give us [a demo to work with](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest the following, though this suggestion may well change once I see the relevant HTML:

```
$('.dhcp').click(
    function(){
        $(this).closest('tr').find('.subnet_mask').hide();
    });
```

This assumes that there will be only one `.subnet_mask` element per row (otherwise this will hide all of them) in response to the click event. You mention that this depends upon a checkbox, so perhaps the following would be better, using the `change()` method:

```
$('.dhcp').change(
    function(){
        var that = $(this);
        if (that.is(':checked')) {
            that.closest('tr').find('.subnet_mask').hide();
        }
        else {
            that.closest('tr').find('.subnet_mask').show();
        }
    });
```

References:

- [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/).
- [`:checked` selector](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/).
- [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/).
- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/).
- [`is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/).
- [`show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/).

Comment: great answer, makes sense and I appreciate the references, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather do this

```
$('.dhcp').on('click', function() {
    $(this).nextAll('.subnet_mask').toggle();
});
```

Then you show/hide the next `.submask` (assuming one `.submask` per `<tr>`) each time you click the `.dhcp`

Answer (score 0):

You're using next incorrectly. It should be more like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('.dhcp').each(function() {
        $(this).click(function(){
            $(this).next('.subnet_mask').hide();
        });
    });
});
```

For this case, I'm assuming that `.dhcp` and `.subnet_mask` are indeed siblings, wit the latter coming immediately after the former. Otherwise, `.nextAll()` can be substituted for `.next()`

Edited as per point below.

Comment: only works if the `.subnet_mask` is `.dhcp`'s _immediate_ sibling, though (which might very well be the case here :] )